# Angular 4 applies same directive to all divs within iteration

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I am faced with strange behaviour in Angular. I want to render a `div` and style according to information that comes from a database.

**template**

```html
<div *ngFor="let app of apps" >
  <div appApplicationColor [name]="app.name.az">
    <a href="{{app.url}}?token={{token}}" target="_blank">
    <p>{{app.name.az}} </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

App.name.az are ="Əlavə", 'LMS' , 'MHS'
and The appApplicationColor directive is

**component**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appApplicationColor]'
})
export class ApplicationColorDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() name: string;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef , private renderer: Renderer2) 
  {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.name = 'Əlavə') {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'yellow');
    } else if (this.name = 'LMS') {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');
    } else if (this.name = 'MHS') {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color' , 'green');
    } else {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
    }
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

The problem is that all divs become yellow instead of according their `app.name.az`. The strange is that when I inspect divs [name] and `app.url` are different in each. The console outputs 'Əlavə' 3 times which means angular directive does not change the [name] property dynamically.

Comment: That's very strange - I was getting the same issue as you, but as I was tweaking it - it was resolved. Now I can't see a difference between my code and yours. [Here is the plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dbhzrkAApHA3F1V7rWhp?p=preview) if you can spot it!

Comment: Ah! I found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your check you are using

```js
if (this.name = 'Əlavə') {
```

This will actually **set** the name to `'Əlavə'` - you should instead use `===` (See: [Difference between `==` and `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness))

```js
if (this.name === 'Əlavə') {
```

But in this case you would probably be better using a [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) like this

```js
switch (this.name) {
  case 'Əlavə': 
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'yellow');
    break;
  case 'LMS': 
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');
    break;
  case 'MHS': 
    break;
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color' , 'green');
    break;
  default:
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
}
```

[Here is a live plunker demo fixing the problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: It worked like a charm! I did not even realize the problem could be because of this. You are a life saver)) Thank you so much.